# How to check if python unit test started in PyCharm or not?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

Is there a way to check in a python unit test (or any other script) if it is executed inside the PyCharm IDE or not?

I would like to do some special things in a unit test when it started locally, things I would not like to do when the whole thing is execute on the build server.

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you do the opposite thing and check if your scrip is running on the build server? Using PyCharm is not the only possible way to run your test locally...

Comment: @yole Cause I often run the build script on my computer and want it to behave like on the build server at this time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When running under PyCharm, the `PYCHARM_HOSTED` environment variable is defined.

```
isRunningInPyCharm = "PYCHARM_HOSTED" in os.environ
```

Comment: And similarly, it looks as if: `isRunningInSublime3 = os.getenv ("SESSIONNAME") == "Console"`.

Comment: Actually not so, it seems. Ignore my previous comment