# skip unit test but run it manually from PyCharm

Tags: unit-testing, pycharm, python-3.7

I would like to use `@unittest.skip` to have my automated testrun pass by some long-running tests. I want to still be able to run them from PyCharm manually. However, when I add the attribute PyCharm is no longer able to execute the test. It fails immediately if the attribute is on the class level. It runs the class initialization and then skips the method if I attribute the method instead. I'm using the "Unittests" runner. Any workarounds for this? Identifying something as in PyCharm or not is insufficient; I really want something like NUnit's Ignore behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if python unit test started in PyCharm or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777737/how-to-check-if-python-unit-test-started-in-pycharm-or-not)

Comment: Combine the linked duplicate with the [`skipIf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.skipIf) decorator.